# Navigation Bar Icon and Padding CSS issues

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a few issues with my navigation bar on my website [www.thehungryeurasian.com](http://www.thehungryeurasian.com)

1) I've added icons onto my navigation bar, and managed to position those on the right with the CSS below. I positioned the home icon on the left by giving it an ID, then inserting the CSS on the bottom line. But this has meant the tabs next to the home icon have been moved down. How do I fix it so it is within the bar?

```
.navleft {float:left; } .navright {float:right;} .tabs-inner .widget ul {margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;}
.tabs-inner .widget ul, .tabs-inner .widget li a, .tabs-inner .section:first-child ul { background: none; }
#navigationbar {width: 1060px; height: 40px; background-color: #326609; background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px; _background-image: none; position: fixed; top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; z-index: 999; }
.navright li a { padding: 0px !important; } 
#homeiconButton { padding-top: 5px  !important; padding-bottom: 0px !important; padding-right: 10px  !important; padding-left:10px  !important; }
```

2) After adding the icons and the CSS above, my navigation bar lost it's background colour and went clear. I had to add

```
background-color: #326609;
```

to override this. Is there something blocking my CSS for this that I need to remove?

3) last question!

I have white dividers in between my tabs. However, there seems to be padding in between them. How would I remove this? Also, is it possible to just have the dividers on the left side of my navigation bar and not on the right side?

Thank you in advance! I know it's a lot of questions.

Comment: Ignore that curt remark - if he wants a fiddle he can go and make one himself. That being said I would recommend at least listing the portions of your HTML that are relevant to go with your CSS, rather than having to depend on an external link for the markup.

Comment: Thanks for that BoltClock, yes I was a bit shocked. Thank you, I'm still new to this, but I'll remember to do that in the future as my question has been answered now though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1 - Add style `"vertical-align : top"` to all the navigation li items (you can exclude for home icon).

Answer 2 - Question is not very much clear to me. But I can see a background color in your navigation bar.

Answer 3 - Remove the style - `float: none;` from  "#cssnav li" selector styles. You may be giving both border-left and right to the li as white. Remove border-left and just give border-right.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Subha, you really helped. Sorry if this seemed simple, I'm pretty new to this!